# SBS 2003 exchange database optimization period, should it be before the sbs full backup or after backup is done

Tags: backup, exchange-2003, windows-sbs-2003, optimization

i just want to check something.

i always thought that a full sbs 2003 backup (through backup wizard) actually optimized the database of the exchange server.

i was curious to see if you would suggest maybe doing an exchange database optimization after a full sbs 2003 backup or just before a full sbs 2003 backup.

i wanted to play around iwth the optimize interval on the system manager tab.

thanks.
gd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an SBS MVP, I've learned through long experience that if Microsoft hasn't enabled a feature in the SBS setup, then it is probably not a good idea to tinker with it. SBS is a complex product with lots of subtleties. It's best to stick to using the SBS configuration consoles and not to stray outside them. Lots of 'enterprise' guys fall into this trap and live to regret it.

Unless you really have clear evidence that your exchange database needs optimising, then I'd apply the maxim "if it ain't broke, don't fix it".

Comment: +1 for that point.  We all love hand-crafting our config files byte by byte, but I love consistency and repeatability more.  I can't see the average SBS shop having enough email to cause a real problem if it isn't optimized.  (I'm presuming the OP wants to change when Exchange goes through the DB and cleans up unused pages, which is usually done in the early hours of the morning out of the box.)